# Override clean_email() method in Django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

How can i override the default `clean_email()` method in `allauth.account.forms.BaseSignupForm`.
I tried the following in Forms.py:

```
from allauth.account.forms import BaseSignupForm

    class Extended_BaseSignupForm(BaseSignupForm):
        def clean_email(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data['email']
            if "@gmail.com" not in data:   # any check you need
                raise forms.ValidationError("Must be a gmail address")
            if app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
                if data and email_address_exists(data):
                    raise forms.ValidationError \
                        (_("A user is registered with this e-mail address."))
            return data
```

The purpose of overriding is to prevent users from registering with disposable email IDs.

Comment: You should paste the full urls.py.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been made easier in the upcoming version of allauth. You can simply override the `clean_email` adapter method, over here:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/4bb9e0170f37d8196bd0c4a78e83adb7b779c113/allauth/account/adapter.py#L175

Use the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER` setting to point to your custom adapter containing the overriden method.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess updating is now the only solution.

Comment: @pennersr : allauth is awesome. I'm following the same logic for overriding `clean_username` with my regex . However I suppose, the changes have to be replicated in 2 more places i.e. `_generate_unique_username_base` (in allauth) and `UserChangeForm` (in django). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to override the URL to pass your form class to the view as keyword argument.

[This article demonstrates how to override a form in an external view](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app).